# How can I provide description with word count limit using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to provide description with certain word count limitation using Regex.This is my current code, but it doesn't work,as it takes 5 letters together.
checkDiscDesc = Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{5,20}$",description);

**See below image:**

[image]

Comment: Do you want to count actual _words_, or just characters?

Comment: If you want between 5 and 20 *words*, then this regex will do: `(?U)*\w+(?:\s+\w+){4,19}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowing whitespaces i.e. Spacebar.
You can add a space to your RegEx, like this:

```
checkDiscDesc = Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z ]{5,20}$",description);
```

Or you can use \s, which matches any space, tab or newline character.

```
checkDiscDesc = Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z\s]{5,20}$",description);
```

Also, check out sites like https://regexr.com/ which will help you understanding and using RegEx.